# Excel repeated max function

Tags: arrays, excel, max

I have a spreadsheet with three columns (See below)

[image]

You can see `Period` is repeated every 20 rows. I would like to find the maximum value in `Price` (the second column) within  every 20 consecutive periods, and have this entry in the third column, `Max Price`.

Presumably I have to use an array function for `Max` that repeats every 20 rows?

Comment: how many rows in total do you have?

Comment: It can be done in a formula that copies downwards in the natural way. Can’t answer myself as am in a meeting but will upvote the answer that does it in this way.

Comment: There are 7300 rows in total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Period values start in `A2`, Price values start in `B2`, and Max Price values starts in `C2`, you can enter this in cell in `C2` and copy that down the column down:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT("B"&INT((ROW()-2)/20)*20+2&":B"&INT((ROW()-2)/20)*20+21))
```

To get a sense of what it's doing, you can also paste this down another column:

```
="B"&INT((ROW()-2)/20)*20+2&":B"&INT((ROW()-2)/20)*20+21
```

It's building the range string using those calculations, and then the `INDIRECT()` is using that range.

Answer (score 0):

If Period is in Column A,Price in B and max price in C,enter this in cell C2 and fill down:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&(ROW(A2)-1)*20+1&":B"&ROW(A2)*20))
```

It will give the max in rows 1-20, then 20-40 and so on

Comment: Sorry, I cant seem to get that too work. I keep getting a reference error

Comment: whats the name of your worksheet? its most likely that. mine is called "sheet1". Change that bit to match yours